# Ordinal Number Function in Remix Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I want to create a new function based on these codes below, that it can just fill in the ordinal number (first student is started by 1) to track out the struct student info in this case.

That's mean after I give the data of this first student to the struct by `addInfo` function:`["Simon", 20, "CA USA", 10]` Then my expected new function is that I just fill in this unit: 1, then it will appear this student detail

```
\`
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ReferenceTypes {

    address public owner;
    
    struct student {
        string Name;
        uint Age;
        string BirthPlace;
        uint8 Marks;
        
    
    }
    
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    mapping (address => student) public Info;
    
    address[] public student_Info;
    
    function addInfo(student memory _student, address _address) public {
    
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Only admin can add Info!!!");
    
        Info[_address] = _student;
    
        student_Info.push(_address);
    
    } 
    
    function count() public view returns(uint) {
        return student_Info.length;
    }
    }

\`
```

Thanks so much guys

I tried a new mapping but failed

Comment: That's mean after i give the data of this first student to the struct by addInfo function: ["Simon", 20, "CA USA", 10]. Then my expected new function is that i just fill in this unit: 1, then it will appear this student detail

Answer (score 0):

You can make another mapping that leads to your mapping Info.

```
uint public studentsCounter;

mapping (uint => mapping (address => student)) public Info;

function addInfo(student memory _student, address _address) public returns(uint){
    require(owner == msg.sender, "Only admin can add Info!!!");
    Info[studentsCounter][_address] = _student;
    studentsCounter++;
    student_Info.push(_address);
    return studentsCounter-1;
}
```

Thus you can reach your struct by passing studentId(studentCounter) which addInfo returns and students address.

Another approach is to remake you array of addresses.

```
student[] public student_Info;
```

And push struct in this array.

```
function addInfo(student memory _student, address _address) public {
    require(owner == msg.sender, "Only admin can add Info!!!");
    Info[_address] = _student;
    student_Info.push(_student);
}
```

So now you can display studentsInfo buy passing index in student_Info array.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind 2 methods ❤️